# How do i str_split each result output text characters from mysqli database

Tags: php, string, text, split, each

How do i str_split each character result output from mysqli database i have tried:

```
require("init.php");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT item_name , quantity FROM books WHERE book = 1905515");
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $da  = $row["item_name"];    
    $qty = $row["quantity"];     
}    
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name , recharge , details , logo , price FROM promo WHERE code='$da' LIMIT 1");
if($rrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{    
    $code = $rrow["recharge"];

    $see = str_split($code, 2);
    echo "<br/>$see"; // not working fine, outputs 'Array'
    echo "$code"; // working fine
}
```

all i get as result is 'arrary' thanks for your time and impact

Comment: `$see` becomes an array from `str_split`, and thus just echoing that will result in `Array`. If you wish to split all characters, and then echo them all out again, you have to compact that array into a string. `implode('',$see);` might serve you well there? Although I'm unsure why you are doing that ;)

Comment: @Randall No result ouput for your method can you state example code?

Comment: Added multiple examples to an answer for you. Guessing about what you need, but I hope I covered what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few directions here, I will give a few examples.

1) If you are simply wanting to echo out each row column, with a break, then all you need is this:

```
if($rrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{    
    echo '<br>' . $rrow['recharge'];
}
```

2) If you do need to split the 'recharge' column into 2-character array values, and then output those again as a solid string, you could do this:

```
if($rrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{    
    $codebits = str_split($rrow['recharge'],2);
    echo '<br>' . implode('',$codebits);
}
```

3) And if you needed to put each 2-character split on its own html row, you can add that to the implode like this:

```
if($rrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{    
    $codebits = str_split($rrow['recharge'],2);
    echo implode('<br>',$codebits);
}
```

4) However, how or what you are wanting to do with the code from 'recharge', is flexible at this point. Various ways we can go with it, and since its in an array, you can even wrap each array element in more html as you need:

```
if($rrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{    
    $codebits = str_split($rrow['recharge'],2);
    foreach($codebits as $codebit) { 
         echo '<div class="something">'. $codebit .'<span>more html</span></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time and contributions in my solution but this not working fine for my acheivement i wana acheive this full code
 in next post 
    can i really acheive  it in php?

Comment: require("init.php");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT item_name , quantity FROM books WHERE book = 1905515");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $da = $row["item_name"];    
       $qty = $row["quantity"];      $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name , recharge , details , logo , price FROM promo WHERE code='$da' LIMIT 1");
    if($fow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql));
        $code = $fow["recharge"];
    $see = str_split($code, 7);
    $see = implode(' ',$see); 
    for($b = 0; $b<$qty; $b++); 
    echo "<br/>$code";
    echo "<br/>$see[$b]";
    }